# ms-Access Clear a textbox based on a True/False control

Tags: ms-access, textbox, conditional-formatting

I am generating a REPORT of 425 members details and have a TextBox [FULLADDRESS] that trims Address details etc.
`=Trim([HOUSE NAME] & ", " & [STREET] & ", " & [TOWN] & ", " & [COUNTY] & ", " & [POST CODE])`
I have a checkbox "[NoAddressDirectory]" that indicates if the member wishes their details to be seen in the report, if the box is ticked then I need to clear the [FULLADDRESS] text box so it is blank in the report.  I can do it by conditional formatting FONT COLOUR but that still allows someone to copy and paste from the report and see the details.  I need to ensure the FULLADDRESS textbox is EMPTY/Null

I have tried all manner of Conditional Formatting and Code.  I am placing the code in the detail section of the report.

```
If Me.NoAddressDirectory = True Then
Me.FULLADDRESS = Null
ElseIf Me.NoAddressDirectory = False Then
Me.FULLADDRESS = Me.FULLADDRESS
```

In all of the code attempts nothing happens in the report view or print preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot directly set value of controls with VBA behind report. Textbox ControlSource would have to call a function.

Just have conditional expression in textbox ControlSource. Don't see need for Trim function:

`=IIf([NoAddressDirectory], Null, [HOUSE NAME] & ", " & [STREET] & ", " & [TOWN] & ", " & [COUNTY] & ", " & [POST CODE])`

Or do that conditional calculation in query and simply bind textbox to constructed field.

If you were using Trim because some fields might be Null and don't want orphan comma and space, it won't work. Trim only drops leading and following spaces. Use `+` character for some of the concatenation. Using `+` with Null will return Null.

`=IIf([NoAddressDirectory], Null, [HOUSE NAME] & ", " + [STREET] & ", " + [TOWN] & ", " + [COUNTY] & ", " + [POST CODE])`

This does assume there is always [HOUSE NAME] value, if not, will get more complicated.

Comment: June7, thank you.  Conditional expression in textbox ControlSource worked a treat.  Easy when you know how.